# Have downloadButton work with observeEvent

Tags: r, shiny

I want to add functionality that gives the user feedback once they click `downloadButton` in my shiny app (e.g., it gives the user an alert message or toggles ui elements once clicked). Essentially, I want to be able to have `downloadButton` download some data **and** behave like `actionButton`, so that it responds to event triggers. Is this possible? This is how I have my code set up:

```
ui <- fluidPage(
  useShinyjs(),

  downloadButton("download", "Download some data")
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {

  observeEvent(input$download, {  # supposed to alert user when button is clicked
    shinyjs::alert("File downloaded!")  # this doesn't work
  })

  output$download <- downloadHandler(  # downloads data
    filename = function() {
      paste(input$dataset, ".csv", sep = "")
    },
    content = function(file) {
      write.csv(mtcars, file, row.names = FALSE)
    }
  )

}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

This only seems to work if I change `downloadButton` to an `actionButton` element in the ui, but doing this disables the download output.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's a bit of a hack, but you can have the `downloadHandler` function modify a reactiveValue that acts a flag to trigger the observe event:

```r
# Create reactiveValues object
#  and set flag to 0 to prevent errors with adding NULL
rv <- reactiveValues(download_flag = 0)

# Trigger the oberveEvent whenever the value of rv$download_flag changes
# ignoreInit = TRUE keeps it from being triggered when the value is first set to 0
observeEvent(rv$download_flag, {
    shinyjs::alert("File downloaded!")
}, ignoreInit = TRUE)

output$download <- downloadHandler(  # downloads data
    filename = function() {
        paste(input$dataset, ".csv", sep = "")
    },
    content = function(file) {
        write.csv(mtcars, file, row.names = FALSE)
        # When the downloadHandler function runs, increment rv$download_flag
        rv$download_flag <- rv$download_flag + 1
    }
)
```

Comment: Appreciate the help! But curiously this still doesn't trigger `observeEvent`. However I was able to get it working by nesting `rv$download_flag` within an if statement in the `downloadHandler`

Answer (score 3):

Based on divibisan's answer above, I was able to trigger events by nesting  `rv$download_flag` within an if statement in the `downloadHandler`:

```
  # Create reactiveValues object
  # and set flag to 0 to prevent errors with adding NULL
  rv <- reactiveValues(download_flag = 0)

  output$download <- downloadHandler(  # downloads data
    filename = function() {
      paste(input$dataset, ".csv", sep = "")
    },
    content = function(file) {
      write.csv(mtcars, file, row.names = FALSE)
      # When the downloadHandler function runs, increment rv$download_flag
      rv$download_flag <- rv$download_flag + 1

      if(rv$download_flag > 0){  # trigger event whenever the value of rv$download_flag changes
        shinyjs::alert("File downloaded!")
      }

    }
  )
```